# Rig/Armature separated mesh from main body. How do I IK rig without separating body parts/mesh?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, armature

I tried to IK rig a dancing model as depicted [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc2-3zdeMak), but unfortunately, the rigging ripped the thigh mesh away from the hip:

[image]
[image]

How do I IK rig without tearing away body parts from the main body? Especially if the body parts are not joined to the torso.

This is my first time rigging a humanoid.

Edit: I mitigated this somewhat by simply using E key to extend the thigh vertices directly connected to the hips, so when the thigh is rotated out, there is no "separating" thigh from vertices

Comment: Hello, the best would be to join the thigh to the body, does it need to be separate?

Comment: @moonboots, actually, the thighs here were joined to the hips, and the thighs still got separated from hips

Comment: They are within the same object but their vertices don't seem connected

Comment: @moonboots I used ctrl + J to join thighs to hips

Comment: Sure but they are not linked by some faces